# Api request in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

I want to use a recipe API for an app. I have registered and obtained a key for an API. However, I don't know where to put my key in the URL so I can paste it into the browser and get the JSON response. 
This is the example Curl request

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients?fillIngredients=false&ingredients=apples%2Cflour%2Csugar&limitLicense=false&number=5&ranking=1",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "KEY",
    "X-Mashape-Host" => "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com"
  )
);
```

This is what I get when I search the URL:

```
{  
   "message":"Missing Mashape application key. Go to http:\/\/docs.mashape.com\/api-keys to learn how to get your API application key."
}
```

If anyone knows how to create the full URL with the key or another way to get the Json response in Swift it would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I think you should go to http://docs.mashape.com/api-keys to learn how to get your API application key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call an API in Swift, I would recommend using the Alamofire library found here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.

In order to authenticate to an API call you have to follow their documentation to find out how they want you to authenticate. Some services have no authentication, while others use a one time use token and some use an API key passed through the request header. It looks like this API call requires the key and host to be passed through the request header. Using Alamofire, the request would look something like this:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "X-Mashape-Key": "KEY",
    "X-Mashape-Host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com"
]

Alamofire.request("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients?fillIngredients=false&ingredients=apples%2Cflour%2Csugar&limitLicense=false&number=5&ranking=1", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

If you want to test API calls without coding the request in the app before hand, I would recommend downloading an application called Postman. This will allow you to test APIs and see their responses to help you in your swift app.